# Make JSON deserialiser distinguish between a class and a subclass of that class

Tags: c#, session, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, json-deserialization

In an asp.net core mvc application I'm working on, I use sessions to keep track of a List of instances of a model I made called "Rule".

Now, you can't save objects other than strings and integers in sessions I'm pretty sure, so I wrote a Session Extention that Serialises and Deserialises objects so I can save them in the Session.

The main problem I run into is that a Rule can contain either a "Card" that just has a card-face or a "SuitedCard", which inherits Card and also has a card-suit.

So when I serialise and then deserialise the List all of the SuitedCards turn into Cards (resulting in the card-suits dissapearing), I assume because that's the default of the model.

How would I fix this? Is there something I can add to the Session Extention that helps distinguish, or is this a lost cause?

Before trying this with subclasses I tried to do the same thing using interfaces, but the problem is that the Session Extention tries to instantiate the interface, which causes errors.

The SessionExtention

```
    public static class SessionExtentions
    {
        public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        public static T Get<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);

            return value== null ? default(T):
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
```

The RuleList in the Controller

```
        private List<Rule> _ruleList;
        private List<Rule> RuleList
        {
            get
            {
                if (_ruleList == null)
                    _ruleList = HttpContext.Session.Get<List<Rule>>("RuleList");
                return _ruleList;
            }
            set
            {
                _ruleList = value;
                HttpContext.Session.Set("RuleList", _ruleList);
            }
        }
```

The Action where I add items to the List

```
        [HttpPost()]
        public IActionResult CreateRuleSet (CreateRuleSetViewModel model)
        {
            if (RuleList == null)
            {
                RuleList = MockDb;
            }
            List<Rule> rules = new List<Rule>();
            rules.AddRange(RuleList);
                Card card = new Card();
                if (model.CheckBox)
                {
                    card = new SuitedCard(model.Face, model.Suit);
                }
                else
                {
                    card.Face = model.Face;
                }
                rules.Add((new Rule(card, model.Type, 0)));
            RuleList = rules;
            model.Rules = rules;
            return View(model);
        }
```

When I add a new Rule to the List and the page refreshes all of the Rules that used to contain SuitedCards now contain regular Cards. They should remain SuitedCards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried

```
public static void Set<T>(this ISession session, string key, T value)
{
    session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value, new 
    JsonSerializerSettings { TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All }));
}
```

This will include the class names in Json, so it will help better identify the types during deserialization.

Comment: Yes, this did it for me